# How much are "Nap & Gos" in Iceland?

Tags: iceland

Like most people flying from North America, I will arrive in Iceland in the wee hours of the morning. I saw Visit [Reykjanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reykjanes) offers a "[Nap and Go](https://www.visitreykjanes.is/en/food-accommodation/nap-and-go)" where you can rent a hotel room for a few hours near the Keflavik airport to catch up on your sleep.

But they all say to contact the properties for prices. How much are they? Is it half a hotel room price, a quarter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I contacted two properties, [Start Hostel](http://starthostel.is/) and [Hotel Keflavik](https://kef.is/), and they quoted me €‎90-120 (95-127 USD) for May 2023. Both offered roughly a 6-hour stay from 7 am to 2 pm or so.

Start Hostel indicated that Nap & Go rates were 75% of regular stays.

Comment: Also my experience. I stayed at Hotel Keflavik in October 2022 and paid $110 if I recall correctly. Full room price was about $140. It was nice to catch a couple of hours sleep (I just can't sleep on a plane) and have a shower, before my host came to pick me up